# Raspberry Pi 3 as a PPPoE server

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Has anyone successfully set up PPPoE server on PI 3?  I followed the instruction on several sites like the one listed using Raging Penguin library.  It seems to work fine on Fedora and Ubuntu, but doesn't behave correctly on PI.

http://www.howtodoityourself.org/pppoe-server-how-to-do-it-yourself.html

Using Raspbian, I am able to get pppoe-server running, but pppoe-server disconnect the session almost immediately upon connecting.

Also, is there a better alternative to set up PPPoE server on PI?